# Best way to implement "custom" currency in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to add a feature in my Rails web-app called "tokens".

It would be a currency of sort which would be exchanged between users for some services.

ex: "Let me stay one night at your place and I'll give you one "token" "

Is there any good rails gem to help me with this? To be precise this "token" system would be completely separated from any real-world currency, you wouldn't be able to buy it, you'd get some of it when you register or invite new users.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I could recommend is [merit](https://github.com/merit-gem/merit#points), look at the points option. It works similar to coins.

```
current_user.add_points(10, category: 'One night stay')
```